# Using secret passwords in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a rails application, on which I need to send an issue on github if a certain process takes place. To send a post request, I need to use my github username and password. I can't use my password in open. What should I do?

I know something about `secrets.yml` file in rails config but I can't even put my password there. I will put my app on github and anyone can hence access. How should I use secrets.yml file to store my password and use it in my rails app?

Comment: use secrets.yml AND use environment variables. you'll store your secrets.yml as base so that you remember what secrets you need but store the secrets in env variables. take a look: https://github.com/GrowMoi/moi/blob/master/config/secrets.yml

Comment: Where are my environement variables exported to store the password in ubuntu-linux system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options:

1. Set it as an [environmental variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). How you exactly do so is highly dependent on which operating system you use. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do so and how to access it from a Rails application. These variables are visible only locally and won't be seen when you push your code to GitHub.
2. Add your `secrets.yml` to your `.gitignore` file. If you don't have a `.gitignore` file, create one in the root directory of your project. Then, simply add `secrets.yml` to that file. Once you do that, git will forever ignore that file in any commit, push, etc. and won't show up if you push your code to GitHub. However, if you already have a `secrets.yml` file and it has been tracked previously by git, you need to remove that file's history. Details on how to do so can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Comment: If I use ubuntu-linux, what steps should I follow? If I write `<%= ENV["PASS"] %>` then where should I export and write my password? Another problem, what if I am collaborating with someone and he wants to use the app?

Comment: [Here's](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) a very thurough tutorial on environmental variables and [here's](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730/how-do-i-set-environment-variables) a good AskUbuntu question on it. I would recommend editing your `~/.profile` file for session-wide variables. I would also recommend a more detailed variable name such as `GITHUB_PASSWORD` so you know which password it is, in case you have multiple.

Comment: And if you're collaborating, just have the other person set up an environmental variable with the same name and value.

Comment: How do I pass my travis ci tests with this configuration? Travis can't know my password and act accordingly

Comment: Travis CI has [a section in their documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings) on how to define environmental variables for your tests. And if you don't trust Travis CI with your GitHub password, you probably shouldn't be using their service.

Comment: This link to the section mentions that such defined environment variables in travis are not available for pull request with forks. Then if I am collaborating and sending a pull request, how can I access these variables?

Comment: Is you application designed to reach out to a single GitHub account or is it supposed to reach out to whoever run's it's GitHub account? If it's the former, give them the password. Otherwise, let them set their own environmental variables.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't commit the `secret.yml` to your git repository. A `secret.yml` that includes production secrets should only exist on the servers (and only be accessible to server administrators).

Furthermore you might want to use an API token instead of your username and password, because API tokens are easier to change.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good solution for you.

https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted

You can encrypt the password and save it to the db assigned to the user (if you have one of course).

If you don't have a user then you'll be stuck with environment variables and secrets.yml or another similar solution